# Easy way to piecewise fit in Matlab a discontinuous function with varying number of singularities

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I have some discontinuous data which I want to piecewise fit all at once since there is one parameter of the fit which is common to all parts of the function.
The number of discontinuities, and their places vary.

I thought about using a class and holding the discontinuity indices as a data member, and then using a member function with varying number of inputs to be the function I send to Matlab's fit function.

e.g.

```
function f = approximate(obj,varargin)
        f = zeros(size(varargin{1}));
        for i = 1:nargin-3
            x = varargin{1}(obj.segmentStartIdx(i):obj.segmentEndIdx(i));
            f(obj.segmentStartIdx(i):obj.segmentEndIdx(i)) = varargin{2} + (0.25*(1-x/varargin{i+2}).^-2+x/varargin{i+2}-0.25);
        end
    end
```

Apparently, this does not work...
Using fit with

```
fittype = ('fp.approximate(x,A,B,C)');
```

Matlab is throwing out the following error:

```
Error using fittype/testCustomModelEvaluation (line 12)
Expression fp.approximate(x,A,B,C) is not a valid MATLAB expression, has non-scalar coefficients, or cannot be evaluated:
Error in fittype expression ==> fp.approximate(x,A,B,C)
??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
Error in fittype>iCreateFittype (line 371)
    testCustomModelEvaluation( obj );

Error in fittype (line 328)
                obj = iCreateFittype( obj, varargin{:} );

Error in fit>iFit (line 157)
    model = fittype( fittypeobj, 'numindep', size( xdatain, 2 ) );

Error in fit (line 108)
[fitobj, goodness, output, convmsg] = iFit( xdatain, ydatain, fittypeobj, ...

Caused by:
    Error using fittype/evaluate (line 102)
    Error in fittype expression ==> fp.approximate(x,A,B,C)
    ??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

Trying a non member function did not fix the problem, not sure what I'm doing wrong though...
I have simplified this to the following function:

```
function [ f ] = moreArgTestFunc( p, xData )
f = zeros(size(xData));
global segmentStartIdx;
global segmentEndIdx;
for i = 1:length(p)-1
    x = xData(segmentStartIdx(i): segmentEndIdx(i));
    f(segmentStartIdx(i):segmentEndIdx(i)) = p(1) + (0.25*(1-x/p(i+1)).^-2+x/p(i+1)-0.25);
end
end
```

Trying to use it in NonLinearModel.fit, or nlfit results in the following error:

```
Error using moreArgTestFunc (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.
```

So I might be missing something here...

Is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling either NonLinearModel.fit, fitnlm, or lsqcurvefit one has to pass the function's pointer as a parameter. I thought that passing in the function name is sufficient - but apparently it is not.
Using an anonymous function

```
funcToFit = @(p,x) myfunctionName(p,x)
```

and then passing funcToFit instead of myfunctionName as the argument solves the problem.

The varying number of parameters to fit was solved by using a vector of varying size for p.